# CSS grid adding a non existant element when reordering elements using @media

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

Sorry for uploading literally everything don't know how to do elsehow. Here I'm trying to reorder my grid at a certain width so it would repeat paragraph to image but when I do this there is a random space that appears between 1 and 2. When viewing with F12 it gives a space like It's is own element but there is no element it is just the .content section. What is going on?

```css
  * {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2600px;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr)/repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  row-gap: 4em;
}

.content-image {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.aparagraph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: larger;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 965px) {
  .content {
    max-height: 2600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr)/1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .p1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .p2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .p3 {
    order: 4;
  }
  .img1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .img2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .img3 {
    order: 5;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Grid-Pratice</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="content">

      <p class="aparagraph p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>
      <img src="images/Black and White Four Arm Monster Clip Art - Black and White Four Arm Monster Image.png" alt="" class="content-image img1">

      <img src="images/Graphics by Ruth - Monster.jpg" alt="" class="content-image img2">
      <p class="aparagraph p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>

      <p class="aparagraph p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>
      <img src="images/Mono Monster Urban Threads Unique and Awesome Embroidery Designs.jpg" alt="" class="content-image img3"> '
    </section>

  </main>

</body>
```

> For some reason the @media change to u/media when copy pasting too.

[how it looks in my browser run standalone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ndY.png)

Comment: what is your expect result/output?

Comment: Can you put and image of your expected outcome?

Comment: I've added a picture of how it looks  at my browser. When the code is run here through stack overflow via "run code snippet" everything looks the way I want it to but as I try to run the same code in the browser firefox or chrome there is a mysterious space that appears and as I've mentioned it is the main containing element that is shown when hovered onto it not a child of the main containing element.

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code you are using `margin-top : 100px` attribute to your `content` class. Then value 100px is not see as a larger space when your width is large, but in small screens it shows like larger space.

If you want, you can reduce it to `margin-top:50px` like below code. And 50px value is seems good for me.

And another thing is when you are adding the media query it is good go set the `margin-top:0px` and it will remove the mysterious space.

And other thing, I saw in your code you are setting a height for paragraph. It is not an issue when it shown as two columns in large screens. But in small screens (when one column), setting a height for paragraph leads to another space. It's good if you can remove that height also.

Hope below code resolves your issue.

```css
* {
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
   }
    
    body{ 
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    }
    
    header{ 
    background-color: black; 
    padding: 50px 0; 
    }
    
    h1{ 
    font-size:xx-large; 
    text-align: center; 
    color:white; 
    }
    
    .content{ 
    height:1000px; 
    display:grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    margin-top:50px; 
    row-gap: 4em; 
    }
    
    .content-image{
    margin:auto; 
    width:300px; 
    height:300px; 
    }
    
    .aparagraph{ 
    width:300px; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    font-size:larger; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    
@media (max-width: 965px){ 
.content{ 
max-height:2600px; 
display:grid; 
grid-template:repeat(5, 1fr)/1fr; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; 
margin-top:0px;     
}
    
    .p1{ order:1;     }
    
    .p2{ order:2;     }
    
    .p3{ order:4;     }
    
    .img1{ order:2;     }
    
    .img2{ order:3;     }
    
    .img3{ order:5;     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Grid-Pratice</h1>
    </header>
    
            <main>
                <section class="content">
            
                    <p class="aparagraph p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>
                    <img  src="images/Black and White Four Arm Monster Clip Art - Black and White Four Arm Monster Image.png" alt="" class="content-image img1">
    
                    <img  src="images/Graphics by Ruth - Monster.jpg" alt="" class="content-image img2">
                    <p class="aparagraph p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>
    
                    <p class="aparagraph p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum soluta atque voluptatibus amet sint voluptatem illo, eos blanditiis. Ducimus dicta deleniti cum est soluta repellat aliquid asperiores nesciunt recusandae eos?</p>
                    <img  src="images/Mono Monster Urban Threads Unique and Awesome Embroidery Designs.jpg" alt="" class="content-image img3">
                '
                </section>
    
            </main>
    
        </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea why the gap appears when you but margin-top in media queries on grid type displays?